# Angular allow inheritance service declaration in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-services

I've a component HomeComponent and I have two services : AnimalService and DogService

DogService extends AnimalService like that :

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AnimalService {
    constructor() {}
    move(): any {
        console.log('move animal');
    }
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DogService extends AnimalService {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    scream(): any {
        console.log('il crie');
    }
}
```

And then I want to use it by calling scream function inside my component :

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'jhi-home',
        templateUrl: './home.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['home.scss']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private dogService: DogService) {}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.dogService.scream(); // the error here : scream is not a function
        }
    }
```

But I have the following error :

```
this.dogService.scream is not a function
```

Maybe there is a subtility with angular, becaus of Injectable or something like that, I know that the constructor of DogService is not called, si my webbrowser undertands that it's an AnimalService. it's not the case if I do a `dogService = New DogService` instead of declaring it inside the constructor. But I don't understand why.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried registering your services in the `module` instead of `providedIn`  flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the annotation in your SuperClass. Don't annotate AnimalService. It must be an abstract simple class.

```
export abstract class AnimalService {
    constructor() {}
    move(): any {
        console.log('move animal');
    }
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DogService extends AnimalService {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    scream(): any {
        console.log('il crie');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP intention is to be able to use the superclass on its own too. If it is not annotated then it could not be used as a service. Maybe he/she needs to rethink the design if this is not possible.

Comment: I agree. What I intended to show was, that inheritance among services only works if only one `class` gets the Injectable annotation and this has to be the inheriting class.

Comment: In that case, make `AnimalService` an abstract class (without the @Injectable), and create a separate implementation of `AnimalService` (with the @Injectable). That way, `DogService` can still extend the abstract, and a separate injectable instance can be created

Comment: @Lynx Thanks for your answer. Yes I would like to continue to use AnimalService. So finally what I did is the following : I duplicated `AnimalService` in an abstract class `AbstractAnimalService` and I extended `DogService` on that. In that way I can continue to use AnimalService and if I want use DogService with all features (both implemented in the abstract class and the DogService himself). Don't hesitate to tell me if it's a good practice or not !

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you. :-) Yes, your approach with the abstract class that gets used by AnimalService and DogService is a good one. Really well done.